# bind a grid to form without using mvc

Tags: extjs

I am trying to bind a grid data to a form in extjs. when i click on a grid row, the details should be populated in form. Can i do that in a simple way without using MVC. I have wrote the below code. help me further. Thank you

```
// JavaScript Document
Ext.require('Ext.data.Store');
Ext.require('Ext.grid.Panel');
Ext.define('User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [ 'id','name', 'email', 'phone' ]
});

Ext.onReady(function() {

var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    data: [
        { id: '1', name: 'srb', email: 'srb@gmail.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { id: '2', name: 'srv', email: 'srv@gmail.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: userStore,
    width: 400,
    title: 'All Users',
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'id' ,
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: 2
        },
        {
            text: 'Email Address',
            flex: 3,
            dataIndex: 'email',
        },
        {
            text: 'Phone Number',
            flex: 2,
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }
    ],
    listeners : {
    itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
     var nm= record.get('name');     
}
},
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet',{
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    margin: '0 0 0 10',

title:'User details',

defaults: {
    width: 240,
    labelWidth: 90
},

defaultType: 'textfield',

items: [{
    fieldLabel: 'Id',
    name: 'id'
},{
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    name: 'name'
},{
    fieldLabel: 'Email Id',
    name: 'email'
},{
    fieldLabel: 'Phone Number',
    name: 'phone'
}]
    });

});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you be more specific in what is wrong in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Ext.form.Panel` instead of `Ext.form.FieldSet`. Field set is more of a decorating container. The form panel provides support for loading / saving data from the form, etc.

Then you need a way to access your form panel in your click event. The absolute simplest is to set an `id` on the form, and use [`Ext.getCmp`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp) to get a ref to the form. Since you've already got the record there, you can just use the [`loadRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord) method of the form panel.

And you'll be done! Be happy to have named your model & form fields the same ;)

The final call in the event listener will look like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('myForm').loadRecord(record);
```

Comment: BTW, you'd better catch the [`selectionchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-selectionchange) event. Clicks may be somewhat uncorrelated to actual row selection.

Answer (score 0):

what version of extjs are you using?

you don't seem to have a form defined or instantiated.

in your grid's itemclick event handler, you need to get a reference to the form, and call form.loadRecord with the passed in record (2nd argument):

```
itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
     var form = getAReferenceToTheFormObject();
     form.loadRecord(record);     
}
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4TSDu/74/